# Worklight Environment specific build for external server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using WL 6.2.0.1 Enterprise edition and we have four environments (DEV-QA-UAT and PROD) where each one of them has a different server path like Dev: (https://mobile-dev.company.ca) QA: (https://mobile-qa.company.ca) ....

When we do the build for our project targeting the external server, this URL is being added to the WL/Device binaries which makes each build unique for that environment.

Is there a way that we can modify the server path after doing the build so in this way we have one base build and we can move it across the environments without doing the build again.? like a WL property that can be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By default when performing a `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server` this will inject to worklight.plist (for iOS) and wlclient.properties (all other environments) the `protocol`, `host` and `port` values of the development server.
- When you want to build your application so that the injected server values will be of a remote server, you will perform a `Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target`, where you will supply those values. When repeating this action with different values, the new values will be injected instead... The UI supports 1 remote server at a time to enter details for.

  So I'm thinking that you could put aside ready worklight.plist/wlclient.properties files to drop into the generated native project(s).

Comment: Thank You Idan, Actually all my builds are running through scripts starting from targeting remote servers until generating the .wlapp/native files. So, there is no load on building the app for different remote servers. Just wanted to see if WL support maybe a configuration to modify the remote server after the build. I know that server path will be implemented inside worklight.plist and wlclient.properites for the generated native folder, but what about the .wlapp is it also environment specific? I think yes, but where can I find the server path inside the .wlapp binary. just as curiosity?

Comment: The .wlapp does not contain any connectivity properties; the .wlapp contains meta data and web resources - these are deployed to the server. Only the generated native projects contain the server IP address, etc. You can have your scripts edit the worklight.plist/wlclient.properties files post-build with other values.

Comment: Great, so I believe, If I did the build for Dev environment which will generate (.wlapp) binaries are also can be deployed to our QA- UAT and PROD environment without rebuilding again since they are not environment specific, the only thing that will change is native binaries which need to be taken care of depending on the environment itself (.ipa - .apk ... etc) right?

Comment: The .wlapp and native projects are the same regardless of the environment. The only thing you need to take care of is the server that the native app will connect to. This is determined in the worklight.plist/wlclient.properties file... this file gets compiled together with the app in Xcode/Android Studio/ADT/Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a partial answer, but you might find some useful tips in [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewferrier1/building-effective-and-rapid-applications-with-ibm-mobilefirst-platform) from slide 25 onwards.